# create file with sudo but have ownership as current user

Tags: sudo, centos6.5, permissions

I am on centos 6.5.

I have a limited user. I gave the user some specific rights via sudoers.

Lets say its user1. I want user1 to create a file in a directory where he has ownership.

Therefore I run

> sudo touch test.txt

Now test.txt is created with ownership root:root.

Is there a way that I can force text.txt to be created with ownership user1:user1?

Note that user1 cannot run chown. I do not want user1 to be able to chown either. User1 is an exposed user.

Note 2:

Also note that I am running these command via php (phpseclib) and authenticating via public/private key.

Thanks

Comment: And `sudo -u user1 touch test.txt` is out of the question?

Comment: `touch test.txt`, without sudo?

Comment: I presume from the question that the original `sudo` is run as some user *other* than `user1`.  You're dead right that is simplest **IFO** (s)he's running it as `user1`, but then the restriction on `chown` makes little sense, as `user1` seems to have arbitrary `sudo` privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would run touch as the user without sudo, I guess...

Assuming that you made a typo and your third line actually reads

> Lets say its user1. I want user1 to create a file in a directory where
>   he does **not** have ownership.

Then you are out of luck, that is not possible. However, there are 2 ways of still achieving what you want:

1. Use ACLs to give user1 permissions on that folder.
2. Create a group called "folderperm" or whatever, chgrp "folderperm" that folder and then assign the sticky bit to that folders permissions (chmod g+s foldername). Now, assuming that one way or another you get to create a file in that folder, it will always have the foldername group as owner and if you can deal with only this (not the user as owner) then you have a solution.